# SQL: Joining on max value

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table with values such as:

```
tableA

ID   |  Value | Year
________________________

1      500      2010
```

and a second table with data such as:

```
tableB

ID   |  Year |  Value
__________________________
1     2010     400
2     2010     100
```

I want to join the tables on the Year but also, I want join where tableA's value is greater than tableB's value, but only want the highest Value to be joined such that the result would look like:

```
RESULT

a.ID |  a.Value  |  a.Year  |  b.Value
_______________________________________
1        500        2010      400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT a.Id,a.Value,a.Year,MAX(b.Value)
FROM tableA A
JOIN tableB B ON A.Year = b.Year AND b.Value < A.Value
GROUP BY a.Id,a.Value,a.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.value, A.year, B.value  
FROM TableB B, TableA A  
WHERE B.year=A.year AND A.value > B.value;
```

What exactly do you mean when you say "but only want the highest Value to be joined"?